# How do I Concat a loop of a char random array?

Tags: c#, loops, variables

I have a char array like this:

```
char[] true_false = new char[2]{'V','F'};
```

A variable random:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

I have a string called `generate_code`, with the initial value is `true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)].ToString();`

```
string generate_code = true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)].ToString();
```

And the user will set the `int lenght_of;`

```
int lenght_of = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

So, what I am trying to do is: the user will define the `lenght_of` that will be  the lenght of the `generate_code` like this:

```
 for(int i =0; i < lenght_of;i++){
    generate_code = generate_code + (char)true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)];
 }
```

But the problem is that I need a fixed variable like :

```
generate_code = (char)true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] + (char)true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)];
```

if `lenght_of =2;` and I have a loop that will change the `generate_code` value ten times.How can I do that? **I hope that u guys understand it is hard to explain.

Example:

```
lenght_of = 2;

 //Example "FF"; 
generate_code = true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] + true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)];

for(int i =0; i < 10;i++) { 
    Console.WriteLine(generate_code); 
} //Output expected: "FF" "VV" "FV" "VF" "FF"
```

Comment: I certainly don't understand what you're asking. Perhaps you can show us some example input and expected output of your function.

Comment: Ok.
Input-->
lenght_of = 2;
generate_code = true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] + true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)];  //Example "FF";
for(int i =0; i < 10;i++){
Console.WriteLine(generate_code);
}
//Output expected:
"FF"
"VV"
"FV"
"VF"
"FF" (..10 times)

Its not working like that

Comment: Are you looking for all combinations of the letters found in the array?

Comment: If you are trying to add the newly generated string to the original string, you should be doing so using `StringBuilder`

Comment: If i use StringBuilder,I will have the same problem that I am having ,that I have to define the generate_code variable size depends on the value of the "size_of" variable.I'm trying to do like that:  for (int i = 0; i < lenght_of; i++)
            {
                generate_code.Append(new[] { generate_code.ToString(), true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] });
            }

Comment: It should be **length** (not *lenght* - the `h` belongs after the `t`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding two `char`'s together. `char` is a numeric type.. therefore you're getting numbers as the result. Also, your `generate_code` assignment must be inside your loop:

```
for(int i =0; i < 10;i++) { 
    generate_code = string.Format("{0}", generateCodeWithLength(rand, true_false, lenght_of));
    Console.WriteLine(generate_code); 
}
```

Wrap the code generation in a method that accepts the length:

```
public string generateCodeWithLength(Random rand, char[] true_false, int length) {
    var result = new StringBuilder(length);

    for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        result.Append(true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)]);
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Or better yet.. a `StringBuilder`. [Clicky clicky live example](http://ideone.com/MFhCwz).

Comment: It is working fine but the user will define the lenght of the generate_code, for example: if the variable "lenght_of" equals 3(if user type that), the generate_code will be : generate_code = true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] + true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] + true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)];.

Comment: The live example on IDEOne is also updated if you want to click it and have a play.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh generate_code in each iteration of the loop:

```
for(int i =0; i < 10;i++) { 
   int loopCounter = 0;
   while (loopCounter < length_of)
   {
       generate_code += true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)]; //Add one more char to generate_code
       loopCounter += 1;
   }
   Console.WriteLine(generate_code); 
} //Output expected if length_of = 3: "FFV" "VFV" "FVF" "FFF" "VVV"
```

That way, each output will be random.

Comment: Also, make sure you don't add two char values together. Join them in the proper way.

Comment: but the problem is that, I will have to define the varible first , so I will choose it size, defining the lenght_of varible, for example: if lenght_of equals 3, the generate_code will be true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] + true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] +true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)]; Soo, I cannot will do your loop.

Comment: Also you must cast the return value into a char or string!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can also do something like:

```
for(int i =0; i < 10;i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}", true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)] + true_false[rand.Next(0, 2)]));
}
```